# Problems when mapping the buttons of my Wacom intuos Draw Pen (ctl-490)

Tags: drivers, hardware, settings, tablet, wacom

i have a problem with my intuos draw pen tablet buttons, it's a model ctl-490, it has 4 buttons on the pad, two on the left and two on the right and 3 on the stylus (two buttons by a side and one more if we count tapping as a button)

My problem is with the pad buttons, when i open this screenon the wacom settings to map them the buttons are in the wrong order.
[image]

If i press the lower left button the upper left button is pressed instead and if i press the upper left button the upper right button is pressed, the lower left button is correctly mapped however but the upper right doesn't work at all

I have o clue of how to fix this and although i don't really need them to draw on krita, i do find them usefull to do some quick editing and moving the canvas.

I use the Ubuntu Gnome 16.10 LTS distribution by the way.

If i'm allowed i would also like to ask a few extra question:

Can one of the buttons on the stylus be set to scroll(both up and down or even left and right)?

Are there other tools to configure wacom tablets apart from the one from out-of-the-box? Are they better or worst?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please use xsetwacom to map your ExpressKeys.

Example:

```
xsetwacom set "Wacom Bamboo Pad pad" Button 1 "key esc"
xsetwacom set "Wacom Bamboo Pad pad" Button 3 "key F11"
xsetwacom set "Wacom Bamboo Pad pad" Button 8 "key ctrl alt t"
xsetwacom set "Wacom Bamboo Pad pad" Button 9 "key p"
```

Where "Wacom Bamboo Pad pad" is the name of your tablet obtained with:

```
xsetwacom --list
```

please see:
http://linuxwacom.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Consumer_Tablet_ExpressKey_Mapping_Issue